# The minimum perimeter and maximum height of a triangle under constraints

Tags: geometry

I do not get the following formulas :

- The minimum perimeter of any triangle (abc), given the heights corresponding to the a and b-sides.
- The maximum height corresponding to the side b of any triangle (abc), given the value of its perimeter and height corresponding to the a-side.

Comment: Do not cross-post such questions to mathoverflow, it's about **research-level** mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

- Given the length of two sides $a$ and $b$ (taking $a \ge b$), the perimeter $p$ is constrained by $2a < p < 2(a+b)$.
- Given the length of one side $a$ and the value of the perimeter $p$, the length of a remaining side $b$ is constrained by $\dfrac{p-2a}{2} < b < \dfrac{p}{2}  $ and also by $0<b< p-a$.

Comment: OK, that might be better answered in the duplicate question then. Sorry for the misunderstanding. If I think of a bound which is still worthwhile but lower complexity, I'll update my answer.